# upload pdf or image file to aws bucket java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have to upload multipart file to aws bucket , what i am doing is

```
public String uploadOnBucket(MultipartFile file){

            InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();


            BufferedImage ImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
            ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(ImageFromConvert, extension, os);
            byte[] buffer = os.toByteArray();
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);

            ObjectMetadata meta = new ObjectMetadata();
            meta.setContentLength(buffer.length);
            AmazonS3 s3Client = AwsUtil.s3Authentication();
            s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(uploadedFileLocation, fileName, is, meta).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.Private));
            inputStream.close();

}
```

The above code is working fine for any image ,but when i am trying to upload pdf ,it is giving me exception that "image is null".I can understand that `IMageIO` is causing this problem.But i am unable to resolve this.Please help,i want to upload file comes in multipart to aws bucket whether the file is pdf or image.

Comment: check your code here..`  BufferedImage ImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(inputStream);` , you use BufferImage so it not work for file.

Comment: What else can i use here to upload for image or pdf file or ant .txt file ?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue by directly passing the input stream to bucket like.

```
InputStream is = file.getInputStream();
            ObjectMetadata meta = new ObjectMetadata();
            meta.setContentLength(is.available());
            AmazonS3 s3Client = AwsUtil.s3Authentication();
            s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(uploadedFileLocation, updatedFileName, is, meta)
                    .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.Private));
```